# Is there special meaning `foo` string in Rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm reading [railstutorial chapter 5.6.4](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/filling-in-the-layout).

According to the page the following two code serve same tests.
But I can't understand why it works without having the argument `page_title`.
Is there special meaning for `"foo"` string in Rspec?

`spec/support/utilities.rb`

```
def full_title(page_title)
  base_title = "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App"
  if page_title.empty?
    base_title
  else
    "#{base_title} | #{page_title}"
  end
end
```

`spec/helpers/application_helper_spec.rb`

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe ApplicationHelper do

  describe "full_title" do
    it "should include the page title" do
      expect(full_title("foo")).to match(/foo/)
    end

    it "should include the base title" do
      expect(full_title("foo")).to match(/^Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App/)
    end

    it "should not include a bar for the home page" do
      expect(full_title("")).not_to match(/\|/)
    end
  end
end
```

`spec/support/utilities.rb`

```
include ApplicationHelper
```

Comment: `'foo'` is a value of `page_title` in this test case. That's it. Look closely for the `full_title` call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the string `"foo"` does not have any special meaning to RSpec, it is just being used as an example in the test to check if the `full_title` helper is working correctly.

To answer the other part of your question, if no page title is passed in, then the if statement will take the first path because the `page_title` variable is empty and you will be returned the base title only. Here is what each of the tests are actually doing:

```
# This is expected to return "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | foo", which
# will match /foo/.
it "should include the page title" do
  expect(full_title("foo")).to match(/foo/)
end

# This returns the same as above ("Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | foo"),
# but this test is checking for the base title part instead of the "foo" part.
it "should include the base title" do
  expect(full_title("foo")).to match(/^Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App/)
end

# This returns just "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App" because the page title
# is empty. This checks that the title doesn't contain a "|" character but that
# it only returns the base title.
it "should not include a bar for the home page" do
  expect(full_title("")).not_to match(/\|/)
end
```

Comment: Thanks, now I understand what for this test. But I'm still confusing. I deleted `full_title` helper method, but the `bundle exec rspec spec/` pass all test. Why `no method error` doesn't occur?

Comment: @Tetsu In the original code in the chapter, the method was duplicated in the spec utilities and in the application helper. If you used the include like you have in your code above, then you can delete the `full_title` method in your spec utilities file with no problems because the include pulls the method from the application helper instead. That may be why you are not getting a no method error.

Comment: great explanation @jvperrin .. it answer my confusing also

Answer (score 1):

This is a "rspec to English" translation of the tests that might help you:

If I give the `full_title` method the string `"foo"`, the result should:

- contain `"foo"`
- contain the base title which is `"Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App"`
- not be `"|"`

The idea behind tests is to make sure your code works using some meaningful examples of the behaviour of the code. You can't test for every possible scenario so you choose one (or more) that describes the functionality of your method the best.

In this case it's passing a string argument `"foo"` which is often [used as a placeholder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foobar) in programming.

Comment: In Japanese, it is `"ほげ"`.

Comment: I just fooled around in irb and found out that `def ほげ; :foo; end;` is actually a valid syntax. Now I wonder how often are non latin characters used in this way.